# Can't output in Russian_Python2.7.9

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I can't make output in Russian language only output of Unicode=(

I use Pythonv.2.7.9
Microsoft 8

How I can do that with list?

```
  #! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("http://fs.to/video/films/group/film_genre/")
response = r.content.decode('utf-8')
page = BeautifulSoup(response)

for tag in page.findAll('li'):
    a = tag.find('a')
    for b in a.contents:
        print (u'{0}'.format(u'○'),unicode(b.string))
```

Example of output must be like:

Аниме

Биография

...

Фэнтези

Эротика

Comment: I use SublimeText 3. Now my output is:
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0410\u043d\u0438\u043c\u0435')
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0411\u0438\u043e\u0433\u0440\u0430\u0444\u0438\u044f')
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0411\u043e\u0435\u0432\u0438\u043a')
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0412\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0435\u0440\u043d')
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0412\u043e\u0435\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0439')
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0438\u0432')
(u'\u25cb', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439')

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
print (u'{0}'.format(u'○'),b.string
```